# Comprobar si una lista no contiene elementos duplicados en Haskell

Tags: lista, funciones, haskell, programación-funcional

Por ejemplo me dan esta lista: `[3,4,5]` y el programa devuelve `True`.
O me dan esta: `[1,2,3,2,5,4,1]` y me devuelve `False`.

Siendo el tipo de la función a definir el siguiente:

```haskell
distintos :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Se que hay que hacerlo de forma recursiva, pero no sé como.

Comment: Hola Ángel, ¿qué código has intentado? ¿Con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: No tengo ni idea acerca de la resolución del ejercicio y por eso pregunto a ver si me podrías explicar como hacerlo

Answer (score 2):

Una forma recursiva de solucionarlo sería preguntar si la cabeza de la lista es elemento de la cola restante utilizando la función elem, que nos dice si un elemento pertenece o no a una lista, si ese elemento pertenece ya sabemos que es falso y podemos parar, si no, seguimos preguntando de forma recursiva para los siguientes elementos de la lista.

```
distintos :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
distintos [] = True
distintos [x] = True
distintos (x:xs) | x `elem` xs = False
                 | otherwise = distintos xs
```

Answer (score 0):

**Metodo 1**

Podemos lograrlo sin recursiva.

Haskell tiene la funcion `nub` (en `Data.List`) que acepta una lista y devuelve la lista con los elementos repetidos eliminados. 
Por ejemplo, `nub [1,2,3,4,2,1]` devuelve `[1,2,3,4]`.

Podemos probar si una lista contiene elementos duplicados o no por comparando el numero de elementos de la lista con el numero de elementos del "version `nub`" de esta lista.

Si todos los elementos de una lista son distintos, el numero de elementos de esa lista será igual al numero de elementos del *version nub* de la misma lista.

Y la funcion es como asi:

```haskell
import Data.List

distintos :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
distintos x = length x == (length (nub x))
```

Si la lista contiene solo elementos distintos, devuelve `True`. De otra manera, devuelve `False`.

---

**Metodo 2**

Si no quiere utilizar el funcion `nub`, puede utilizar este metodo.
Ordenamos la lista, y agrupar los mismos elementos con el funcion `group` (tambien en `Data.List`).

```haskell
> a = [2,3,1,2]
> group (sort a)
[[1],[2,2],[3]]
```

Y luego calculamos el `length` de cada sublista. Si una sublista no tiene duplicados, el `length` devuelve `1`.
Es decir que una lista sin elementos repetidos es una lista en cual las sublistas todas tienen `length` igual a `1`. Probarlos con el function `all`.

El codigo final:

```haskell
distintos :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
distintos x = all (==1) (map (length) (group (sort x)))
```

O puede escribirlo en una manera mas legible utilizando el operador de composicion de funciones (`.`):

```haskell
distintos :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
distintos x = all (==1) . map (length) . group . sort $ x
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias pero me gustaría saber si existe otra implementación sin tener que usar la función nub de Haskell

Comment: @ÁngelGarcíaGonzález he añadido otro metodo